# How to programatically get all linked items for a given Sitecore item?

Tags: admin-pages, related-items

I'm wondering if there is some API/Code/Trick on Sitecore to **fetch all linked/related Items** to a given Sitecore item, just like we have on the XP Admin interface?

My goal here is to find all pages using a given item as a data source of one of its renderings.

[image]

Comment: Something like `Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers({current item})` or I missed the point of your question?

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks Marek :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use from code:             `ItemLink[] itemLinks = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item);`

Or from Content Editor you can use Link ribbon button from Navigate tab:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Link Database via `GetReferrers` method.
e.g.

```
var links = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item);
  if (links == null)
    return new Item[0];
  var linkedItems = links.Select(i => i.GetSourceItem()).Where(i => i != null);
```